# Change value of select when a holiday is write in input

Tags: jquery

I want to change the selected value from my "atividade" select when a date is typed by the user in my input field

This is my date input:

```
<input class="mask-date form-control" size="9" id="data" name="data" type="text">
```

and when a specific date is write I want to change the value of my option to "Feriado" if that is a holiday

```
<select class="chosen-select form-control" id="atividade" name="atividade">
<option value="Hora Direta" selected="selected">Hora Direta</option>
<option value="Domingo">Domingo</option>
<option value="Falta">Falta</option>
<option value="Folga">Folga</option>
<option value="Feriado">Feriado</option>
<option value="Atestado">Atestado</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying this jquery and works to change the value of input fields but I cant change my select value, I tried like so but not works:

```
$('#data').focusout(function(){
    var holidays = ['01/01', '25/12'];
    var date = $('#data').val();
    var day = date.substr(0,5);

    if (jQuery.inArray(day, holiday) != -1)
    { 
      $("#atividade").val("Feriado");
    }

 });
```

Basically what this jquery does is if I type a date and is in my array of holidays I want to change my listbox value to "Feriado" and disallow the user to change the value, 
how could I do that ?
Thx in advance!

```
$('#data').focusout(function(){
        var holidays = ['01/01', '18/04', '21/04', '07/09', '12/10', '02/11', '15/11', '25/12'];
        var date = $('#data').val();
        var day = date.substr(0,5);

        if (jQuery.inArray(day, holidays) != -1)
        { 
          $("#divatividade").fadeOut();
          $('#atividade option[value="Feriado"]').prop('selected', 'selected');
        }
        else
        { 
          $("#divatividade").fadeIn();
          $('#atividade option[value="Hora Direta"]').prop('selected', 'selected');
        }
     });
```

working now, added id and class again and i dont know why worked
thx all!

Comment: what is the problem now?

Comment: the problem is change the option to 'Feriado', i tried also:
$("#atividade option[value='Feriado']").attr("selected", "selected");

Comment: It works with me in chrome 33.0.1750.154 (win7). when do you register the event handler ? you might have to wrap it in the `ready` handler making sure that the referenced dom elements have been created (cf. [jquery api doc](http://api.jquery.com/ready/))